# How to retrieve pictures from Instagram

Tags: objective-c, ios9, instagram, instagram-api

I want to get picture from Instagram, but they return blank data to me. Please check - I am new in iOS:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=2315359304.fd72562.3fc48188ce25460185a1e74124f70fed

```
Data 
data =     (
    );
    meta =     {
        code = 200;
    };
    pagination =     {
    };
```

Here is my Code

```
 IGAppDelegate* appDelegate = (IGAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;       

     NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"users/self/media/recent/", @"method", nil];
        [appDelegate.instagram requestWithParams:params
                                        delegate:self];
```

Comment: Add media in your account Instagram. You ([varunsdcet](https://www.instagram.com/varunsdcet/)) have 0 medias.